# vb.net convert array element into string

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

Using the code below to loop through my array which was created by reading a text file with 10 or so lines in it, so each thing in the array is one of those lines from the text file

```
Dim myarray As Array
myarray = Split(stringfromtextfile, vbCrLf)
For each element in myArray
MgBox(element)
Dim splititem As String = Split(element, "\")
```

The message box shows the line as I'm expecting but when I try to split it up I just get the error:

Error   1   Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'.

How do I get the value which was shown in the message box converted to a string to I can then do a split on it?

Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you use .NET methods? For example: `Dim lines=System.IO.File.ReadLines(path).Take(10)` to take the first ten lines from a file. Then to split use `String.Split`.

Comment: Why don'y you use generic `List(Of String)`?

Comment: Are you sure that this is VB.NET code? It looks like VB 6 to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code is invalid:

```
Dim splititem As String = Split(element, "\")
```

The [`Split` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f.aspx) returns an array of strings, but you're trying to assign the result to a variable that represents only a single string.

That's what the error message is telling you: the "value of type '1-dimensional array of String'" is what is being returned from the `Split` function, and that "cannot be converted to 'String'" in order to store it in the `splititem` variable.

Change it to look like this (note the parentheses, which indicate an *array* of String):

```
Dim splititem As String() = Split(element, "\")
```

And do strongly consider using the .NET Framework methods for string manipulation, rather than the old VB 6 methods. They are provided primarily for compatibility purposes with older code, not intended for use in new code.

If you actually *are* writing VB 6 code (which is what this looks like), rather than VB.NET code, you cannot assign variables at the point of their declaration. You'll need to split these up into separate statements:

```
Dim splititem As String()
splititem = Split(element, "\")
```

Comment: Thank's Cody, couldn't see the wood for the trees! Cheers. Yes it's an old vbscript that's being updated to .NET. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I would use .NET methods instead of VB6 methods which are not strongly typed, hence less efficient and - more important -  error-prone and less readable.

For example with LINQ:

```
Dim first10LineFields = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines(path)
                        Let fields = line.Split("\"c)
                        Select fields
                        Take 10
```

Output:

```
For Each lineFields  As String() In first10LineFields 
    Dim fieldsCommaSeparated = String.Join(",", lineFields)
    MessageBox.Show(fieldsCommaSeparated)
Next
```